# Separating variables in the PDE $u_{tt}+2u_t+u=u_{xx}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Separating variables in the PDE $u_{tt}+2u_t+u=u_{xx}$

In the ODE of $T(t)$ (Second last equation) shouldn't it be the one stay outside the bracket?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it should have been outside. And the subsequent steps show this.

Comment: @2mkgz please see the updated attachment.

Comment: I don't see what your question is now.

Comment: Should it be T ̈ + 2T ̇ + (1 − λ)T = 0 or T ̈ + 2T ̇ + 1 − λT = 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error may be earlier. The separation of variables should give:

$\dfrac{\ddot{T} +2\dot{T}}{T}+1 = \dfrac{\ddot{X}}{X} = \lambda$

The next lines look okay:

$\ddot{T} +2\dot{T}+T = \lambda T$

$\ddot{T} +2\dot{T}+(1-\lambda)T = 0$

$\ddot{T} +2\dot{T}+(1+n^2)T = 0$